# function $f(x)=x^{-(1/3)}$ , please check whether my solution is correct?

Tags: calculus, limits, graphing-functions

Let $f(x)=x^{-(1/3)}$ and $A$ denote the area of region bounded by $f(x)$ and the X-axis, when $x$ varies from -1 to 1. Which of the following statements is/are TRUE?

1. f is continuous in [-1, 1]
2. f is not bounded in [-1, 1]
3. A is nonzero and finite

---

I try to explain :

---

graph is  :

[image]

1. False , since left limit is not equivalent to right limit.
2. True , since  f(x) rises to $infinite$ at $x=0$.
3. True , since we can calculate it by doing integrating the function

Comment: 1. is True. Where do you think left- and right-limits do not match, x = 0? But that's not in the domain, and as a delicate part of the definition, continuity (or discontinuity) only applies at points in the domain. So the limits match for all points in the domain, meaning it's continuous.

Comment: And pretty sure 3. is False, because the definite integral does not converge.

Comment: look at [here](http://gateoverflow.in/8124/gate2015-2_26) or [here](http://geeksquiz.com/gate-gate-cs-2015-set-2-question-36/)

Comment: My mistake on 3, I didn't read the bounds specification on A. It's also True. So they're all True.

Comment: See here for note on restriction of continuity to points in domain: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1431796/if-a-function-is-undefined-at-a-point-is-it-also-discontinuous-at-that-point/

Comment: As I read , this is a polynomial function , it should be continuous as well as differentiable (for this function), Am I rt ?

Comment: But official key says 1 is false [see Q.no. 56](http://gate.iitk.ac.in/GATE2015/AnsKey2015/CS_S06.pdf)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29578/discussion-between-user4791206-and-daniel-r-collins).

Comment: I would say that the official key is mistaken, given standard definitions of continuity.

Comment: This happened rarely , this is standard exam [GATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graduate_Aptitude_Test_in_Engineering) [GATE-16](http://www.gate.iisc.ernet.in/)

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: $f$ is certainly _not_ continuous on $[-1,1]$.It is continuous on $[-1,0) \cup (0,1]$, but that was not the question.

Comment: @TonyK That's a good point, thanks for the correction.

Comment: I'm very very confused :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** Although your answers contain some true aspects,  your reasoning is not completely satisfying. Most of them is due to the incomplete specification of the function $f$. It's **absolutely crucial** to be fully aware about the *[domain and codomain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function)* of a function. Otherwise no precise analysis of a problem is possible. You may want to check the example in the section *formal definition* right at the beginning of the referring wiki-page, which addresses a function  similar to your problem.

In order to be able to properly answer your question, we add a  domain and codomain of $f$. But note, that other domains/codomains are possible. And this changes the question and also might change the answer.

> **Question:** Let $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with $f(x)=x^{-\frac{1}{3}}$ and let $A$ denote the area of region bounded by $f(x)$ and the $X$-axis, when $x$ varies from $-1$ to $1$. Which of the following statements is/are TRUE?
>
> 1. $f$ is continuous in $[-1, 1]$
> 2. $f$ is not bounded in $[-1, 1]$
> 3. $A$ is nonzero and finite

$$ $$

> **Answer:**
>
> The statement 1. is FALSE. Reasoning: In order to be continuous in $[-1,1]$ the function $f$ has to be continuous at each point of $[-1,1]$. Since $f$ is *not defined* at $x=0$, it is neither continuous nor discontinuous at $0$.  But $f$ is continuous in $[-1,1]\setminus{\{0\}}$.

Comment to your reasoning *since left limit is not equivalent to right limit*:

You are addressing the point $0$, so you should specify it because at all other points in $[-1,1]\setminus{\{0\}}$ the left limit of $f$ is equal to the right limit. The term *equivalent* has a specific mathematical meaning, so you should instead use the term *equal*.

> The statement 2. is FALSE. Reasoning: In order to be bounded in $[-1,1]$ the function $f$ has to be defined in $[-1,1]$ which is not true for $x=0$. Furthermore $f$ is not bounded in $[-1,1]\setminus{\{0\}}$ since e.g. the limit $lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}=-\infty$.

Comment to your reasoning *since $f(x)$ rises to $infinite$ at $x=0$*:

Since the function $f$ is not defined at $x=0$ it is better to write *since $f(x)$ rises to $infinite$ when $x$ tends to zero*. This formulation considers only values $x$ within the domain of $f$.

> The statement 3. is FALSE. Reasoning: It is assumed that $x$ varies within the domain $[-1,1]\setminus{\{0\}}$ of $f$ and we further assume the area $A$ is a signed area. Since integration of the positive part of $A$ results in
>    \begin{align*}
>  \lim_{a\rightarrow 0^+}\int_{a}^{1}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}\,dx&=\frac{3}{2}\lim_{a\rightarrow 0^+}\left. x^{\frac{2}{3}}\right|_a^1=\frac{3}{2}
>  \end{align*}
>    which is finite, we obtain due to symmetry $A=0$.

Comment to your reasoning *since we can calculate it by doing integrating the function*.

The wording is not precise enough, since we are able to calculate an integral and the result might be $\pm\infty$. We have to state that we get a *final value* by integration.

Usually when integration is involved, we consider areas as *signed*. That's why I calculated $A=0$. But maybe, according to your conventions with respect to such questions, you have to consider an unsigned area. In this case we obtain $A=3$ and your answer TRUE is correct.

**[2015-09-29]** Add-on regarding the term **discontinuity**

The term *[continuous function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuousFunction.html)* is defined with respect to its domain. Therefore it's crucial to specify the domain of a function, if we want to analyse the function with respect to continuity. Outside of the domain of a function this function is not continuous, since it's not even defined there.

Note that when we talk about *[discontinuities](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Discontinuity.html)* of a one variable function we classify them as either being a *removable discontinuity*, a *jump discontinuity* or an *essential resp. infinite discontinuity*. The key point here is, that each of these discontinuities is defined with respect to the *domain of $f$*. We conclude, discontinuities are defined *solely* within the domain of $f$.

Regrettably we often see different explanations which talk about *discontinuities* at points where a function is *not defined*. A typical example is 
\begin{align*}
&f:\mathbb{R}\setminus{\{0\}}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
&f(x)=\frac{1}{x}
\end{align*}
$f$ is not continuous at $x=0$ since it's not even defined there. But we should not say  $f$ is *discontinuous* at $x=0$, since the term discontinuity is due to it's classification in different types *only defined* within the domain of $f$. Alas, we can read such statements often.

The situation is *completely different* when we instead consider 
\begin{align*}
&g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
&g(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x}&x\neq 0\\
0&x=0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
The function $g$ is also defined at $x=0$. Here we can conclude that $g$ has a discontinuity at $x=0$.

Another example: Let's consider the *[arithmetical function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function)*
\begin{align*}
&h:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
&h(x)=x
\end{align*}

This function has domain $\mathbb{N}$ and it's not useful to consider properties of $h$ at points outside of it's domain.

*Informally:* The domain and codomain specify where the function *lives* and we can't say anything about the function outside of its region of existence.

**Conclusion:** Since this terminology is not uniquely used within the community it's presumably helpful to discuss this aspect with a teacher to find a common sense.

Comment: I'm very very confused here , unable to decide anything . Please , give me some more hint or reference to read (I want to fix this problem).

Comment: @user4791206: Another example added, which could help to clarify this aspect.

Comment: sir , well ,I tried to understand your solution carefully . I found some point during my investigation , 
(1) a function is continuous if you can draw its graph without picking up your pencil [here](http://www.math.brown.edu/UTRA/discontinuities.html) , 
(2) types of discontinuous functions [here](http://www.analyzemath.com/calculus/continuity/continuous_functions.html) , [here-also](http://math.mit.edu/~jspeck/18.01_Fall%202014/Supplementary%20notes/01c.pdf) ,  [wiki-non-example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Non-examples)

Comment: I also read [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_function) of bounded function . I'm satisfied by your solution , for continuous or bounded function should be defined , in other word, point should be from domain . for statement 3 it $A$ may be zero .

Comment: I'm able to say all given statements are false . Greetings and thanks to your solution

Comment: @user4791206: Good to see the answer is useful for your serious study. One last (small) word of warning. Drawing a graph without picking up the pencil is only a *rough guideline* for continuity. Consider the function $f:[0,1]\cup[2,3]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=0$. This function *is* continuous, but when you look at its graph ... :-)

Comment: rt sir , (that is not formal definition) :)

Comment: sir , I want more discussion http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495246/if-a-function-is-not-continuous-then-is-it-possible-for-bounded-function-in-give

Answer (score 3):

The following statements certainly have standard definitions: 1) "$f$ is continuous at $x$" ; 2) "$f$ is continuous".  For the function $f(x) = x^{-1/3}$, it's certainly true that "$f$ is continuous" and that "$f$ is not continuous at $0$".

However, what about the statement, "$f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$"?  Perhaps there is some confusion or disagreement over the meaning of this statement.  I think that the statement "$f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$" means that "if $x \in [a,b]$ then $f$ is continuous at $x$".

By that definition, statement 1) is false because the function $f(x) = x^{-1/3}$ is not continuous at $0$.

So, for $f(x) = x^{-1/3}$, the statement "$f$ is continuous" is true, but the statement "$f$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$" is false.

Comment: it seems meaningful .

Comment: The reason for 1 being false is also that $f(0)$ is not defined in the first place.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm curious, do you object to my statement that "statement 1) is false because the function $f(x) = x^{-1/3}$ is not continuous at $0$"?  Or are you just clarifying that, the reason $f$ is not continuous at $0$, is that $f$ is not even defined at $0$.  I ask to check if I'm missing some subtle point.

Comment: I need more discussion http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495246/if-a-function-is-not-continuous-then-is-it-possible-for-bounded-function-in-give