# Is this function $f(x)=x^{-1/3}$ continuous, when $x$ varies from $-1$ to $1?$

Tags: integration, continuity, graphing-functions

I have doubt ! regarding to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1453187/function-fx-x-1-3-please-check-whether-my-solution-is-correct) ,

---

> Is this function $f(x)=x^{-1/3}$ continuous, when $x$ varies from $-1$
>   to $1?$

[image]

---

As I read, when left limit is not equivalent to right limit ,then function is not continuous . For this function  $f(x)=x^{-1/3}$ should not be continuous , since it's undefined at $x=0$ , [check-here](http://www.themathpage.com/acalc/continuous-function.htm#cont) or [here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/continuity.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In modern mathematics, the definition of continuity discards points that fall outside the domain of definition. In other words, continuity must be checked *only* at point of the domain. Since your function is defined on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, it is continuous at every point of its domain of definition.

Comment: Well , in [linked-question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1453187/function-fx-x-1-3-please-check-whether-my-solution-is-correct) , are all statements true ?

Comment: In my opinion, the first question is almost meaningless. As I said, it is rather unfair to ask whether a function is ocntinuous outside its domain.

Comment: You are correct sir , but  $f$ belongs in $[-1,1]$

Comment: No, $[-1,1]$ is not a subset of the domain of $f$. Unless, of course, you decide to define $f(0)=$ something. In this case, the *extended* function will be discontinuous.

Comment: so , I cancluded $f$ is continous everywhere except $x=0$ , rt ?

Comment: sir , I want more discussion http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495246/if-a-function-is-not-continuous-then-is-it-possible-for-bounded-function-in-give

Answer (score 1):

You're right: It only makes sense to say that a function $f$ is continuous in $x$ if $x$ is in the domain of $f$, i.e. if $f$ is defined in $x$.

Let me add that for other examples it could be possible that $f$ can be extended to a continuous function
$$
\tilde{f}(x) = \begin{cases} f(x), &x\neq 0,\\ c, & x=0,\end{cases}
$$
with some value $c\in\mathbb{R}$, which is then a function defined on the larger domain $[-1,1]$ including $x=0$ (one says that $f$ possesses a *removable discontinuity in $0$* if that works).
You only obtain a continuous function by that process if $c = \lim_{x\nearrow 0} f(x) = \lim_{x\searrow 0} f(x)$ and this is obviously not the case in your example, since $\lim_{x\nearrow 0} f(x) = -\infty \neq \infty = \lim_{x\searrow 0} f(x)$.