# If a function is not continuous then is it possible for bounded function in given range?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity, bounded-variation

I [posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454781/is-this-function-fx-x-1-3-continuous-when-x-varies-from-1-to-1) this problem before [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1453187/function-fx-x-1-3-please-check-whether-my-solution-is-correct) .I have satisfied explaination given by [markus-scheuer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/132007/markus-scheuer) sir and [siminore](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/29672/siminore) sir . I also found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1431796/if-a-function-is-undefined-at-a-point-is-it-also-discontinuous-at-that-point) .

I have read the Wikipedia posts for [continuous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function) and [bounded function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_function) and I have concluded that a function should be defined on given range for satisfying conditions of continuity and bounded function .

I posted my answer at GateOverflow(a site old Q/A of GATE ) , but they not accepted my answer and they have given reason answer key is correct , but not my explanation .

---

> Let $f(x)=x^{-(1/3)}$ and $A$ denote the area of region bounded by
>   $f(x)$ and the $X-$axis, when $x$ varies from $-1$ to $1$. Which of the
>   following statements is/are TRUE?
>
> 1. $f$ is continuous in $[-1, 1]$
> 2. $f$ is not bounded in $[-1, 1]$
> 3. $A$ is nonzero and finite

---

Given answer key of this question $:$

1. False
2. True
3. True

---

In my opinion all given statement should be false .

---

My doubts are $:$

1. If a function is not continuous then is it possible for bounded function in given range ? What about function in given problem .
2. Is it possible bounded area zero or infinite ? What about statement $(3)$ of problem ?

Comment: Sorry but I think this question would do better if it was rewritten. Getting rid of everything above 'original problem is', and rewrite the question with $\LaTeX$.

Comment: Done , please suggest me , if anything more .

Comment: The leading section is necessary because of the links. It is not clear how this question differs from the previous version, what are the new problems or misunderstandings. The given answer was comprehensive, with answers for alternative interpretations of the question. As it is, this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Please reopen this problem for atleast one week ,  I want more discussion . Please vote for reopen .

Comment: The function $f(x)=\sin (1/x)$, no matter how you define it at $x=0$, is discontinuous. However its range is $[-1,1]$.

Comment: means , a function which is defined on given range may be discontinuous function . But continuous function must be defined on given range , rt ?

Comment: @Siminore: The continuity of $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ depends on the domain of $f$. If the domain of $f$ is specified e.g. as $(0,\infty)$, the function is continuous at each point of its domain and therefore continuous.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer sir , yes . I support this.

Comment: @Silence Yes, according to every definition I have ever seen, continuity is defined at points of the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) A non continuous function can be either bounded (e.g. step function, see $g(x)$ below) and unbounded (e.g. the function in the question).

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
1& x>0\\-1 & x\le 0
\end{cases}
$$
2) If $f$ is not bounded, how does it possible that the area bounded between $f$ and the X-axis is finite? Very roughly, area is height times width, $f(x)$ is the height here, and the width is a segment of $x$.  The segment is finite, but since $f(x)$ is unbounded it is not, and therefore the area cannot be finite.

In addition, if the length of the segment (the width) is not zero and the function (the height) is not zero everywhere, the area cannot be zero as a product of two non zero numbers.