# finding points of discontinuity of the function $f(x) = e^{x + (1/x)} $ and state their types..

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, continuity

finding points of discontinuity of the function $f(x) = e^{x + (1/x)} $ and state their types.

**My answer:**
this function has an essential discontinuity at 0, am I correct?

Comment: The function is undefined at $0$

Comment: yes this is what I said ...... are there any other points at which the function is undefined? @Holo

Comment: you said it is "discontinuous" at 0, there is a difference between discontinuous and undefined(and no, there are no other points which this function undefined)

Comment: correct but discontinuities are found at points where the function is undefined correct? @holo ...... so my answer is correct?

Comment: no, [look here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1431796/if-a-function-is-undefined-at-a-point-is-it-also-discontinuous-at-that-point) to see discussion about this. But generally, a function is neither discontinuous nor continuous at points it does not defined.

Comment: @Happy The "functions" tag is used for questions about properties of functions/mappings in a set-theoretical frame such as injectivity and surjectivity. Please do not abuse this tag.

Comment: okay I am sorry I will delete it @AlexFrancisco

Comment: Do you mean “singularity” instead of “discontinuity”?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe  No I mean discontinuity.

Comment: Your answer is correct. There are no other discontunuity points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A key data about $f$ is missong: its domain and codomain.

Anyway. It is simpler to deal with $e^{1/x}$ and, once you have understood it, may be multiply it by $e^x$ and then try to apply L'Hospital rule or something.

For complex numbers $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, the imaginary poles of the function
$$f(z)=e^{1/z}$$
around $z=0$ are easily figured out: For any integer number $k$,
$f$ has a pole at
$$z_k=\frac{1}{2\pi ik}.$$
Now notice that, for any positive radius $r>0$, the domain of $f$ restricted to the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $z_\infty=0$ has an infinite number of poles. Thus $f$ has an [essential singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity) at $0$.

Now I ask you to complete the reasoning and comment: If $e^{1/z}$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$, then which type of singularity does $e^{z+1/z}$ has?