# Is the function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) = \exp(1/\sqrt{x^2-1})$ continuous in a topological sense?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I've recently started learning about topology, and I was able to prove that any function which is undefined on a countable subset of $\mathbb R$ is also not continuous. However, I am struggling to prove the same claim for a function which is undefined on an uncountable subset of $\mathbb R$. Here's my proof for the countable case:

Denote the set of points upon which $f$ is undefined as $A$. Then, the preimage of the empty set is $f^{-1}(\emptyset) = A$. If $f$ is continuous, then $A$ should be open (as $\emptyset$ is open). However, the singleton set is not open with respect to the usual topology over $\mathbb R$, and since $A$ is a countable union of singleton sets it must also not be open. Hence, the preimage of an open set is not necessarily open, meaning $f$ is not continuous over $\mathbb R$.

This proof breaks down for me, because if $A$ is uncountable it can possibly be open. Taking the function defined by $f(x) = \exp\Big(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\Big)$ as an example, the corresponding set $A$ for this $f$ is $A = (-1, 1)$. In this case, $f^{-1}(\emptyset) = (-1, 1)$ is open, so that means $f$ does take open sets to open sets... and so $f$ is continuous.

Can anyone please explain the flaw in my logic?

Comment: A function that is undefined at some points on $\mathbb{R}$ is, by the two modern definitions of function, not considered a function.

Comment: If $A$ is the set where $f$ is undefined no, it absolutely does not follow that $A=f^{-1}(\emptyset)$. (That would say $f(t)\in\emptyset$ for every $t\in A$...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Ahhh, I understand that was not a valid step. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @plop I don't know if that makes sense. Wouldn't that imply that any map with removable discontinuities isn't a function? Or that the natural logarithm isn't a function?

Comment: @BayleeV the point is that the natural log is not considered a function *on $\mathbb{R}$* but it is a function on the positive reals. Similarly, you can't speak of functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$ but aren't defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$ - this just doesn't make much sense. The idea is that they are defined on $\mathbb{R}$ "minus some points" but we can still discuss continuity for such functions.

Comment: @IskyMathews I see. So how would one formalize that $f(x) = x/x$ is discontinuous at $x = 0$, for example? The preimage (by this $f$) of any open set would be either $\mathbb R - \{0\}$ or $\emptyset$, depending on whether or not 1 is in the set, and both of these are open, implying that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: The function you have mentioned IS continuous at every point in its domain. It is NEITHER continuous nor discontinuous at $x=0$ as it is undefined at that point. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1431796/if-a-function-is-undefined-at-a-point-is-it-also-discontinuous-at-that-point

Comment: To be clear, continuity of $f:X\to Y$ relates the value of $f(x_0)$ to the value of $f(x)$ where "$x$ is close to $x_0$" (where the specific relation depends on the definition). Both $x$ and $x_0$ are members of $X$ - this is, more than anything, deeply important. This means we can have continuous functions $f:\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{R}$ which is a very different thing to continouous functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{Q}$ etc. What if I asked you whether or not $x^2$ was continuous at $x=elephant$? This doesn't make sense as elephant is not in the function's domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your understanding of the concept of *function* is not the standard one. A function $f : X \to Y$ assigns to **each** input $x \in X$ a unique output $f(x) \in Y$.

Therefore the notation $f :  \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ implies that $f$ is defined **on all of $\mathbb R$.** There is nothing like a function $f :  \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ which is undefined on a nonempty subset of $\mathbb R$. What you have in mind is sometimes called a *partial function*. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=partial+function) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function). But if you consider a partial function $f : X \to Y$ between topological spaces $X,Y$, you must be aware that it is actually a function $f : X ' \to Y$ defined on some $X' \subset X$. The continuity of $f$ *has nothing to do* with the points of $X \setminus X'$.

However, denoting certain *partial functions* as *functions* is well accepted in some contexts. In complex analysis (which does probably not belong to the field of your experience at the moment) one uses the concept of *[meromorphic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function)*  on open subsets of the complex plane. Meromorphic functions are in fact partial functions in the strict sense.